# Rails Csv.new where is this class being called from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, roo-gem

I'm creating my own version of Rayan Bates CSV screencast here...

http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel

I have this in my model...

```
 def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xls" then Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
```

...and am getting this error in my app...

```
 NameError in StudentsController#import

uninitialized constant Student::Csv

Rails.root: /home/wintas/railsApps/t4
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/models/student.rb:25:in `open_spreadsheet'
app/models/student.rb:13:in `import'
app/controllers/students_controller.rb:12:in `import'
```

I can't find where the class 'Csv' is initialized, or where it should be coming from. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that since that Railscast was published, Roo has been updated to namespace `Csv`, `Excel`, and `Excelx` under the `Roo` namespace. Try this instead:

```
def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Dylan, that worked. But its strange. I am using all the same rails version and gem as Ryan's base app.

Comment: @Lumbee but are you using the same version of the gem? That Railscast used 1.10.1, whereas it's currently at 1.13.2.

Comment: When using Roo::Csv is still getting error, please try to Roo::CSV. I hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

Newer equivalent of that function using roo 1.13.2 is:

```
def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, file_warning: :ignore)
    when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, file_warning: :ignore)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, file_warning: :ignore)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ruby standard library, csv is all caps: CSV.  Does that help?

Comment: `Csv` is a class within the `Roo` gem, different from Ruby's stdlib `CSV` class.

Comment: Yes I realize, but in the Railscast tutorial, it appears, Ryan Bates is using the ruby CSV library to start with, so I thought this might be a source of confusion for the OP.  In anycase, you're probably right, its probably a gem version issue necessitating namespacing

Comment: Turns out @PeterP was correct about the capitalization but not for the correct reason. See jesai's answer as that is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

try restarting the server;
I had the problem before and restarting the server resolved the issue